# How to add new values to a custom field

Tags: 7, entities

I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere.

Programmatically, I need to add new values to a custom field of a new node instance I just created via API.  I am taking input via a form and want to add that data to the custom field in the new node.  I know the columns of the custom field.

How can I do that, or where is a good reference?

(the custom field type is address, if that matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a custom form which is invoked by a menu callback, you could try this.

Assuming that you have a postal address field type (provided by the [addressfield](http://drupal.org/project/addressfield) module) which as 5 sub-fields - country, address 1, address 2, city and postal code in your content type.

```
/**
 * This will be invokded by a menu callback
*/
function yourmodule_custom_form($form, &$form_state){

    /* your form elements definition here */

    $form['#validate'][] = 'yourmodule_custom_form_validate';       
    $form['#submit'][] = 'yourmodule_custom_form_submit';

    return $form;
}
/**
 * Validation attached to the form
*/  
function yourmodule_custom_form_validate($form, &$form_state){
    // do validation here
}
/**
 * Submit handler attached to the form
*/
function yourmodule_custom_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
    global $user;
    $values = $form_state['values'];

    # Create a node object, and add node properties.
    $node = new stdClass();
    $node->type = 'your_content_type';
    $node->uid = $user->uid;
    $node->created = strtotime("now");
    $node->changed = strtotime("now");
    $node->status = 1;
    $node->comment = 0;
    $node->promote = 0;
    $node->moderate = 0;
    $node->sticky = 0;
    $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;

    $field_address = $values['field_address'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0];

    $node->field_address_country = $field_address['country'];
    $node->field_address_thoroughfare = $field_address['thoroughfare'];
    $node->field_address_premise = $field_address['premise'];
    $node->field_address_locality = $field_address['locality'];
    $node->field_address_postal_code = $field_address['postal_code'];

    node_object_prepare($node);
    # Save the node.
    # The node will also get published, if $node->status was set to 1.
    node_save($node);
    $nid = $node->nid;
    # if you want to redirect to a page after submission, use this
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'path/to/redirect';
    drupal_redirect_form($form_state);
}
```

I did not test the code. It is just for example. You may need to amend it by yourself.
You can inspect your address field name by printing out `$form`.

```
dpm($form); // if you have devel module enabled
echo '<pre>'; print_r($form); echo '</pre>'; // if you don't have devel moduel
```

Also note that when you create a new field, Drupal creates two new tables starting with **field_data_field** and **field_revision_field**. If you name the field "address", you will see two new tables **field_data_field_address** and **field_revision_field_address**, you could look up into those tables.

Comment: Sithu, I am presenting a regular form to gather the data.  How would this hook be called after the user submits the form?

Comment: I may have answered my question.  Do I use hook_form() and test the node type and call my custom form?

Comment: Are you rendering a custom form which is invoked by a menu page callback? Can you please expand your question?

Comment: Yes, it is a custom form invoked by a menu callback.  I need to do some extra validating and processing on the input data before it is added to the custom field.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: Sithu, I think that is what I'm looking for.  The addressfield field has several values in its schema.  How do I set the individual fields with their values?

Comment: I just updated my answer. I hope you are not looking for ready-made code. You could inspect `$form` and `$form_state` to know what the field names are. You can also find out in the field table, for example, **field_data_field_address**.

Answer (score 0):

Sithu, thanks for your help.  That worked.  In the end, Drupal made it easier than I was thinking it would be.  I'll post my code and do a walk-through when I get some time.

Comment: Glad to hear that. But this is not an answer. You should just leave a comment.